# sql server query is not working in delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi

i have this code:

```
DECLARE @top VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @top =STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT
                '],['+ ltrim([itemID])
                FROM ARInvDet 
                ORDER BY '],['+ ltrim([itemID])
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, '')+']'


SET @sql ='
SELECT ItemID,Quantity,Price FROM(
select * From (
select 
a.CustomerID as [CustomerID],
a.DateFinalize as [Date],
ad.Quantity as [Quantity],
ad.UnitPrice as [Price],
i.ItemTypeID as [ItemTypeID],
i.ItemID as [ItemID]
from ARInvDMS a 
inner join ARInvDet ad on a.ARInvoiceID = ad.ARInvoiceID
inner join item i on ad.ItemID = i.ItemID
WHERE CustomerID = 10056 and a.[DateFinalize] = CONVERT(DATETIME,''2/28/2014'', 102)
and i.[ItemTypeID] = 1
) src

PIVOT 
(
    SUM(Quantity)
    FOR [ItemID] in ('+@top+')

) as pvt
) as src2
UNPIVOT
(
    Quantity FOR ItemID in ('+@top+')
) as unpvt

'

execute(@sql)
```

the error is Incorrect Syntax near '2': it from the WHERE statement.. but i tried to run this code in sql server 2008 r2..and its working fine.. but when i used this in my delphi program.. this error appears.. please help.

Comment: How exactly do you run this code in Delphi? Note that you need some ' handling

Comment: You've provided no information related to how you're trying to use this in your Delphi code. If you don't post Delphi code, we can't help you solve problems with your Delphi code. "My head hurts. Here's a picture of my foot. Why does my head hurt?" is not a question that can be answered.

Comment: Try the SQL in SSMS first to make sure it is correct. For instance using '],[' in @top doesn't look right to me. Some other points - if DateFinalize is a datetime then you don't need the convert. I suggest you always specify dates in yyyymmdd format. Also you don't need the [] around names in most instances.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the doubled quotes around the date.

If you run this query in SQL Server exactly as you show it here, it will choke on

```
''2/28/2014''
```

because it needs to be surrounded with single quotes.

```
'2/28/2014'
```

Now let's talk about how you're going to run this query from Delphi.
Are you putting this text into a query object at design time?
Or are you using it as a string constant within your program?

If you're just setting the SQL text at design time, you can enter the raw query directly as is, once you've corrected for the doubled quotes.

If you're using a string constant, you need to double every single quote:

```
const 
  sqlSCRIPTXXX = 
        'DECLARE @top VARCHAR(2000)'
+ #13#10'DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)'
+ #13#10'SELECT @top =STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT'
+ #13#10'                ''],[''+ ltrim([itemID])'
+ #13#10'                FROM ARInvDet '
+ #13#10'                ORDER BY ''],[''+ ltrim([itemID])'
+ #13#10'                FOR XML PATH('''')'
+ #13#10'                ), 1, 2, '''')+'']'''
+ #13#10''
+ #13#10''
+ #13#10'SET @sql ='''
+ #13#10'SELECT ItemID,Quantity,Price FROM('
+ #13#10'select * From ('
+ #13#10'select '
+ #13#10'a.CustomerID as [CustomerID],'
+ #13#10'a.DateFinalize as [Date],'
+ #13#10'ad.Quantity as [Quantity],'
+ #13#10'ad.UnitPrice as [Price],'
+ #13#10'i.ItemTypeID as [ItemTypeID],'
+ #13#10'i.ItemID as [ItemID]'
+ #13#10'from ARInvDMS a '
+ #13#10'inner join ARInvDet ad on a.ARInvoiceID = ad.ARInvoiceID'
+ #13#10'inner join item i on ad.ItemID = i.ItemID'
+ #13#10'WHERE CustomerID = 10056 and a.[DateFinalize] = CONVERT(DATETIME,''2/28/2014'', 102)'
+ #13#10'and i.[ItemTypeID] = 1'
+ #13#10') src'
+ #13#10''
+ #13#10'PIVOT '
+ #13#10'('
+ #13#10'    SUM(Quantity)'
+ #13#10'    FOR [ItemID] in (''+@top+'')'
+ #13#10''
+ #13#10') as pvt'
+ #13#10') as src2'
+ #13#10'UNPIVOT'
+ #13#10'('
+ #13#10'    Quantity FOR ItemID in (''+@top+'')'
+ #13#10') as unpvt'
+ #13#10''
+ #13#10''''
+ #13#10''
+ #13#10'execute(@sql)';
```

I have a utility that I wrote just to do these conversions.  The code above is the output of that utility.

So, in this case, the quotes around the date are doubled, and so are all the other quotes.

Comment: yep i set it that way... sorry i forgat to post my solution.. but thanks..